# Axios get request status 503 if i call it inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I want to make ten api calls to populate an array. If i make the same api call but outside of the for loop i don't get any problem. But doing it inside the for loop i get some succesfull requests and a ton with a 503 status code, service unavaiable.

Here is my js:

```
function generatePersonJson() {
  const promise = axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "User-Agent": "axios 0.21.1",
    },
  });
  const dataPromise = promise.then((response) => response.data);
  return dataPromise;
}

const createPerson = async () => {
  generatePersonJson()
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        return data
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

const createPersons = async () => {
  let personsArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    const person = await createPerson();
    personsArray.push(person);
  }
  console.log(personsArray);
};

createPersons();
```

I get the error in the catch block inside the createPerson and it looks like this: `response: { status: 503, statusText: 'Service Unavailable',`

Comment: In createPerson function, you have to return the entire thing.. just add return keyword before generatePersonJson()

Comment: createPerson need not be async as it does not use await inside

Comment: Sounds like your server can't handle the load.

Comment: You are probably hitting a rate limit or other limit on the server you're calling.

Comment: I replaced axios with the node-fetch and works perfectly, seems like axios.get makes an instant call and that's why i get a 503 but with fetch is really slow but returns everything.

Comment: you should probably span out your requests with some time frame like 1 request per 10 seconds